# Integrating IM applications with outlook 2010/2013

Tags: c#, com, outlook-2010, outlook-2013

I have implemented the IM application (name is "ContactCardDesktop.exe") as suggested by the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900715(v=office.15).aspx
I have done all the registry setting per the article. but there is no call to outlook to IM application  for function GetAuthenticationInfo() and GetInterface().
Even not getting the ProcessID at registry location HKCU\Software\IM Providers\ContactCardDesktop.

In outlook logs I am getting errors attached below. I have gone through to many suggestion but didn't get help much.
Please suggest the problem/solution.

Sample code for Application.

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(_IUCOfficeIntegrationEvents))]
    [ProgId("LitwareClientAppObject.Class")]
    [Guid("449B04AD-32A8-4D21-B0AE-8FC316E051CE"), ComVisible(true)]

    public partial class LitwareClientAppObject : IUCOfficeIntegration
    {
        IMClient imClient;
        Automation imAutomation;

        public LitwareClientAppObject()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            imClient = new IMClient();
            imAutomation = new IMClientAutomation();
        }
        // Implementation details omitted.
        public string GetAuthenticationInfo(string _version)
        {
            string supportedOfficeVersion = "15.0.0.0";
            // Do a simple check for equivalency.
            if (supportedOfficeVersion == _version)
            {
                return "<authenticationinfo>";
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public object GetInterface(string _version, OIInterface _interface)
        {
            IMClient imClient = new IMClient();
            IMClientAutomation imAutomation = new IMClientAutomation();
            switch (_interface)
            {
                case OIInterface.oiInterfaceILyncClient:
                    {
                        return imClient;
                    }
                case OIInterface.oiInterfaceIAutomation:
                    {
                        return imAutomation;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                    }
            }
        }

        public OIFeature GetSupportedFeatures(string _version)
        {
            OIFeature supportedFeature1 = OIFeature.oiFeatureQuickContacts;
            OIFeature supportedFeature2 = OIFeature.oiFeatureFastSearch;

            return (supportedFeature1 | supportedFeature2);
        }
```

Errors like:

- CMsoIMProviderFactory::HrEnsureDefaultIMAppRegKeys Succeeded opening reg key (HKCU:SOFTWARE\IM Providers)
- CMsoIMProviderFactory::HrEnsureDefaultIMAppRegKeys Succeeded querying reg key (HKCU:SOFTWARE\IM Providers:DefaultIMApp:ContactCardDesktop)
- CMsoIMProviderFactory::HrEnsureDefaultIMProcessRegKey Succeeded opening reg key (HKCU:SOFTWARE\IM Providers\ContactCardDesktop)
- CMsoIMProviderFactory::HrEnsureDefaultIMProcessRegKey Succeeded opening reg key (HKLM:SOFTWARE\IM Providers\ContactCardDesktop)
- CMsoIMProviderFactory::WhichMessengerInProcessList Using (ContactCardDesktop.exe) process name for search

  - CMsoIMProviderFactory::WhichMessengerInProcessList Using (ContactCardDesktop.exe) process name for search  hr = 80040154, We couldn't identify the provider type we now try to manually CoCreate using the LCClient CLSID
- CMsoIMProviderFactory::HrGetAvailableProvider !failed!  Line: 409  hr = 0x80040154  hr = 80040154, We couldn't identify the provider type we now try to manually CoCreate using the LCClient CLSID
- 
- 
- CMsoIMProviderFactory::HrGetAvailableProvider !failed!  Line: 289  hr = 0x80004005  !!!Provider Initialization Failed!!!
- 

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue to use COM server "CSExeCOMServer" that is at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSExeCOMServer-3b1c1054

Comment: hi, i'm interesting in integrating my IM app with office too. I can't see how to put CSExeCOMServer within my code. Would you have some tips ? thanks !